# React: conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design-lite

I have got a react component that renders conditionally, i.e.:

```
 render() {
        if (this.state.isFoo) {
            return (
               <div className='bar'>
                   <Baz />
               </div>
            );
        } else {
           return (
            <div>
              <TextField /> <Button>search</Button>
           </div>
           );
        }
 }
```

In `<Baz />` there is a `dropdown` from `getmdl-select`. If I include the first part of `render` without checking if `isFoo` is true then the dropdown is rendered correctly. By correctly I mean, the user can select an option. But with the conditional rendering, as shown in the example, the options are not selectable. The drop-down does not expand and the options are not visible. Is it because the `getmdl-select.min.js` does something at loading time?

NB: The `search` button activates the `isFoo`, i.e. it sets it to true so that rerender is requested.

Comment: r u not missing a return in the else? not that it is related, also, it seems ur tags are not propewrly closed, maybe the WMD fau;t.

Comment: <TextField /> <Button>search</> this format is not valid too

Comment: Updated the question. It was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your render must return the React elements you want to render. You are missing a return for your else part and your button is not closed correctly. Here's an example of conditional if else rendering.

```
render() {
        return (
          this.state.isFoo
            ?  
             <div className='bar'>
               <Baz />
             </div>
            :
             <div>
               <TextField /> <Button>search</Button>
             </div>
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would code it.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.isFoo) {
        return (
           <div className='bar'>
               <Baz />
           </div>
        );
   return (
        <div>
          <TextField /> <Button>search</>
       </div>
    );
}
```

I use this approach a lot when using a loader